# Set custom font to dynamically added text view android

Tags: android, fonts

I am adding a TextView to a LinearLayout at run time.
I want to set a font at run time from my `assets/fonts/` folder.
I have done the following, but it is not working:

```
private ArrayList<TextView> getExperTextViews() {
    ArrayList<TextView> textViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView tv_title = new TextView(DesignerDetailActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parms.setMargins(0,0,0,5);
    tv_title.setLayoutParams(parms);
    Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");
    tv_title.setTypeface(font);
    tv_title.setText("EXPERTISE");

    tv_title.setTextSize(16);

    textViewArrayList.add(tv_title);
    ArrayList<DesignerExpertise> designerExpertiseArrayList = designer.getExpertiseArrayList();


    String expertiseString = "<font color='#a8a8a8'>{property}</font> &nbsp;";
    for (int i = 0; i < designerExpertiseArrayList.size(); i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(DesignerDetailActivity.this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        DesignerExpertise designerExpertise = designerExpertiseArrayList.get(i);
        ArrayList<DesignerExpertiseValue> designerExpertiseValueArrayList = designerExpertise.getDesignerExpertiseValues();

        String newExpertiseString = expertiseString.replace("{property}", designerExpertise.getProperty().toUpperCase());
        newExpertiseString = newExpertiseString + designerExpertiseValueArrayList.get(0).getName();
        for (int j = 1; j < designerExpertiseValueArrayList.size(); j++) {
            newExpertiseString = newExpertiseString + " ," + designerExpertiseValueArrayList.get(1).getName();
        }
        Typeface _font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        tv_title.setTypeface(_font);

        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newExpertiseString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        tv.setPadding(0,5,0,5);
        textViewArrayList.add(tv);
    }
    return textViewArrayList;
}
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was a copy/paste mistake. In your `for` loop, the code should be `tv.setTypeface(_font)` instead of `tv_title.setTypeface(_font)`

```
for (int i = 0; i < designerExpertiseArrayList.size(); i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(DesignerDetailActivity.this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    DesignerExpertise designerExpertise = designerExpertiseArrayList.get(i);
    ArrayList<DesignerExpertiseValue> designerExpertiseValueArrayList = designerExpertise.getDesignerExpertiseValues();

    String newExpertiseString = expertiseString.replace("{property}", designerExpertise.getProperty().toUpperCase());
    newExpertiseString = newExpertiseString + designerExpertiseValueArrayList.get(0).getName();
    for (int j = 1; j < designerExpertiseValueArrayList.size(); j++) {
        newExpertiseString = newExpertiseString + " ," + designerExpertiseValueArrayList.get(1).getName();
    }
    Typeface _font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(_font);

    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(newExpertiseString), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    tv.setTextSize(16);
    tv.setPadding(0,5,0,5);
    textViewArrayList.add(tv);
}
```